# SQL Server joined tables doesn't filter records as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server tables which I'm trying to join and get this expected output but not working quite. The table `OECMTHST_SQL` contains multiple rows which share the same `real_ord_no` number also in each of those rows the `ord_no` number column varies.

`OECMTHST_SQL` table.

[image: dbfiddle screenshot]

Now the second table `OEHDRHST_SQL` has `ord_no` column which can be multiple entries with unique `invoice_no` column. Note: this `invoice_no` column is same as the other table's (`OECMTHST_SQL`) `ord_no` column.

`OEHDRHST_SQL` table

[image: dbfiddle 2]

Now as you can see in the `OECMTHST_SQL` table the `real_ord_no = 200022` has repeated 7 times but out of that 4 rows share `ord_no = 214736` and rest of them share `ord_no = 214738`.

Now my goal is to get a query that filer out by `ord_no` that does not have a `cmt = PA_INV:SUCCESSFULLY SENT`. So as per this example the correct output would be only `214738` and `214739`.

**Note**: `PA_INV:SUCCESSFULLY SENT` will always be in the `cmt_seq_no = 4` as that's the pattern.

Here is the sample dbfiddle for the tables : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hut7x0pI)

Here's what I've tried

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    O.ord_no
FROM
    OECMTHST_SQL O
INNER JOIN
    oehdrhst_sql H ON LTRIM(RTRIM(O.real_ord_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(H.ord_no))
WHERE
    O.cmt NOT LIKE 'PA INV%%'
    AND H.ord_type = 'O'
    AND O.cmt LIKE 'Inv_Email%%'
    AND H.entered_dt > '2022-09-29 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY
    o.ord_no
HAVING
    SUM(cmt_seq_no) < 10
ORDER BY
    O.ord_no
```

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    O.ord_no,
    SUM(O.cmt_seq_no)
FROM
    OECMTHST_SQL O 
INNER JOIN
    oehdrhst_sql H ON LTRIM(RTRIM(O.real_ord_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(H.ord_no))
WHERE
    H.ord_type = 'O'
    AND H.entered_dt > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101)
GROUP BY
    O.ord_no
HAVING
    SUM(O.cmt_seq_no) < 10
```

None of those queries return my expected output which are `214738` and `214739`. Not sure what is wrong in those queries or if it's incomplete. I appreciate all your help and guidance.

Comment: Why are you using `LTRIM/TRIM` with `ord_no`? Why can't you do a equijoin?

Comment: What is the exact type of `entered_dt` and why are you doing `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate()-1, 101)` ?

Comment: @Dai I've never heard of equijoin, sorry. That might work as well if you say so. And the type of `entered_dt` is `datetime` and the reason I was doing `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate()-1, 101)` is if I do just `getdate()` then it would give me the date and time which I cannot compare with the `entered_dt` column. So I was planning to convert it to get only the date and filter it be greater than yesterday's date, which is given by `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate()-1, 101)`

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot compare with the `entered_dt` column."?

Comment: The `entered_dt` column has only date. And time is not recorded, in that case I thought I cannot compare a datetime field with just date field. Sorry about my less knowledge on data types. Trying to learn as I go.

Comment: I'm just going to assume that you already know that a much better data design would be to have column names and definitions such that `ord_no = ord_no` across tables, rather than confusing things like `invoice_no = ord_no` and `ord_no = real_ord_no`, etc., yes?

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes sir, I certainly do, if I was the database engineer/designer I would never do that, but unfortunately this is a pre-built database from the ERP Software called Macola. Not to mention their database scheme is pretty nasty. Like it or not this is what I have to deal with everyday haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT
O.ord_no
FROM
    OECMTHST_SQL O
    inner join oehdrhst_sql H ON
        LTRIM(RTRIM(O.real_ord_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(H.ord_no))

WHERE
    O.ord_no NOT IN (SELECT ord_no from OECMTHST_SQL WHERE cmt LIKE 'PA_INV%')
    AND
    H.ord_type = 'O'
    AND
    O.cmt LIKE 'Inv_Email%'
    AND
    H.entered_dt >= '2022-09-29 00:00:00.000'

group by
    o.ord_no

having
    sum(cmt_seq_no) < 10

order by
    O.ord_no
```

I see 2 issues with your approach.

First, you want to filter out rows with the same ord_no as a row where cmt starts with 'PA_INV', not rows where that criteria is true.

Second, all of the dates in your sample data are = '2022-09-29 00:00:00.000', so you need a >= comparison if you want to match them.

Also, the having and group by clauses aren't needed for this query, but I left them in case you need them for your real use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the long waited answer I was looking for. It works and give me the results 100% accurate and as expected.